# Is there a way (other than sql) to get the mlid for a given nid in drupal?

Tags: drupal, menu

I've got a node, I want it's menu. As far as I can tell, node_load doesn't include it. Obviously, it's trivial to write a query to find it based on the path `node/nid`, but is there a Drupal Way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Menu Node module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node) exposes an API to do this.
You can read the  documentation (Doxygen) in the code. I think the functionality you need is provided by the `menu_node_get_links($nid, $router = FALSE)` method:

```
/**
 * Get the relevant menu links for a node.
 * @param $nid
 *   The node id.
 * @param $router
 *   Boolean flag indicating whether to attach the menu router item to the $item object.
 *   If set to TRUE, the router will be set as $item->menu_router.
 * @return
 *   An array of complete menu_link objects or an empy array on failure.
 */
```

An associative array of `mlid => menu object` is returned. You probably only need the first one so it might look like something like this:

```
$arr = menu_node_get_links(123);
list($mlid) = array_keys($arr);
```

Otherwise, you can try out the suggestion in a [thread in the Drupal Forums](http://drupal.org/node/592716):

Use `node/[nid]` as the $path argument for:

```
function _get_mlid($path) {
  $mlid = null;
  $tree =  menu_tree_all_data('primary-links');
  foreach($tree as $item) {
    if ($item['link']['link_path'] == $path) {
      $mlid = $item['link']['mlid'];
      break;
    }
  }
  return $mlid;
}
```

Comment: looks like that'll do it, but I think sql is easier... Thanks, though.

Comment: No problem. Indeed SQL might be easier. :)

Answer (score 6):

if the menu tree has multiple levels sql seems a better option.
a sample for drupal 7 is given bellow where path is something like 'node/x'

```
function _get_mlid($path, $menu_name) {

$mlid = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
->condition('ml.link_path' , $path)
->condition('ml.menu_name',$menu_name)
->fields('ml' , array('mlid'))
->execute()
->fetchField();
return $mlid;
}
```